# Form : Send multiple value one after the other

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with an input and a submit button.
In the other hand, I have a list of values for the INPUT "hello".
I want to submit these values one after the other

**My form :**

```
<form action="post.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="hello" id="hello" size="25" value="">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

**My list :** A list containing several words

**My goal :** To send automaticaly "word1", then "word2", then "word3", then "word4" etc.

Comment: i think it would be better if you told us what you are trying to achieve as your end result, and what code have you tried so far. it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Share you post here or give a jsfiddle link.

Comment: I need to send a confirmation email (generated via this form) to my clients / prospects. So the list is emails. When I clic on submit with the email in the uinput, it will send a confirmation email to my clients. I don't know how the confirmation email is generated (The guy before me made it). I only have access to the form.

Comment: Why you need HTML form for this? just send it by ajax to your server url...

Comment: @user3492770 sending the emails one by one via your browser is not very efficient. i suggest you ask the guy before you how his system works and if its possible to submit a whole list of emails, or check the system to see what it accepts. if there is no choice, you could do it with ajax as suggested by oleg.

Comment: Because I have access to this form and it was easier for me because I only "skills" in html and php

Comment: @Banana Ok thank's, I'm going to check with Ajax

Comment: So I tried to get access to the file but I can't. So I don't have other solutions than submitting from the form. So no solution for that ? Efficient or not. I just need to do it once. I can fill in the input manually and then click on submit but I got like 1 000 emails to submit.